# Avoid blank line in fputcsv

Tags: csv, fputcsv, blank-line

Im creating a csv downloads in php using fputcsv. The problem is the file is not supposed to have blank lines. But fputcsv leave a blank line at the end of file always. How can we avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks, i fixed it. Before my code was :

```html
while ($cresult=$stmt->fetch()) {
 $nrow=$nrow+1; 
 if($qiid<>""){
  $visn="";
 }
 //bank code is not taken from sql view
    $list = array($nrow,$qiid,$visn,$nmee,$BNK,$acee,$fre,$atnn,$ntsl,$bscsal,$xtrahr,$xtrain,$didu,$notees,'Vacation');
 fputcsv($output,$list); 
  }
 fclose($output);
 
  
 ?>
```

I added exit() to the end before php closing tab, and it helped to avoid the blank line in the csv downloaded file.
    Now my code is

```html
while ($cresult=$stmt->fetch()) {
 $nrow=$nrow+1; 
 if($qiid<>""){
  $visn="";
 }
 //bank code is not taken from sql view
    $list = array($nrow,$qiid,$visn,$nmee,$BNK,$acee,$fre,$atnn,$ntsl,$bscsal,$xtrahr,$xtrain,$didu,$notees,'Vacation');
 fputcsv($output,$list); 
  }
 fclose($output);
 exit;
  
 ?>
```